# OSX: rm -fr gets No such file or Directory when run from .Core API

Tags: macos, terminal.app, asp.net

Running the above command via a CORE API works fine for most directories but not for one.

Running the command from the terminal works fine.

doing a ls -l on the directory to be deleted: 
  `drwxr-xr-x 7 xxx staff <datestamp> <sub dir>`
doing lsof on the directory gives nothing back

Any idea why this is failing?

Thx

Comment: 1) show the code that doesn't work (and does it print any errors?), and 2) what's the directory's name, how are you specifying the path to it, etc?

Comment: running an rm -rf is dangerous. If an operation fails, the pointer can drop back to the previous directory and you can trash an entire disk. I've seen this happen when using it in bash scripts more than once. It's likely a permissions issue, or a directory marked as protected.

Comment: Also, what does this apply to? Is it OS-X, or ASP? As @GordonDavisson stated, please post the code and directory name, as well as the error message.